How I can mapping Oracle data types to GridDB data types?
I am struggling with mapping Oracle data types to the corresponding GridDB data types. For instance, how should I handle Oracle’s and types when inserting them into GridDB? Are there specific best practices for ensuring data integrity during this conversion? VARCHAR2 NUMBER
import oracledb
import griddb_python as griddb

# Connect to Oracle Database
oracle_conn = oracledb.connect("admin/ali_786@localhost:1521/ORCL")
oracle_cursor = oracle_conn.cursor()

# Fetch data from Oracle table
oracle_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Customers")

# Connect to GridDB
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
griddb_store = factory.get_store(host="192.168.0.13", port=10001, cluster_name="zaigham", username="admin", password="ali_786")
container = griddb_store.get_container("conn")

# Ensure the container is ready to accept data
container.set_auto_commit(False)

# Insert data into GridDB
for row in oracle_cursor:
    # Mapping Oracle row to GridDB types here, assuming the structure is compatible
    container.put(row)

# Commit the transaction to GridDB
container.commit()

# Close connections
oracle_cursor.close()
oracle_conn.close()


Please don't delete one question and ask what appears to be the same question again a day later.

Ok I understand.

Looking at the GridDB types and the Oracle types, you probably want to convert Number to Double, and Varchar2 to String. Should be fine for most uses.

migration from Oracle to GridDB is accurate data type mapping. Here are some mappings that have worked well for me:
Oracle NUMBER ➡️ GridDB DOUBLE or INTEGER: Depending on whether you are dealing with whole numbers or decimals, mapping NUMBER fields to DOUBLE or INTEGER can maintain data integrity.
Oracle VARCHAR2 ➡️ GridDB STRING: Both types handle text, but keep an eye on any maximum length differences between your Oracle schema and GridDB to avoid truncation issues.
Oracle DATE or TIMESTAMP ➡️ GridDB TIMESTAMP: Oracle’s DATE and TIMESTAMP fields should map to TIMESTAMP in GridDB, which is suitable for datetime values.
